# Open binary file data with Spark - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Having the following binary file (mp3) that send audio to a service in Azure to be trascripted.

The following code **works** in Databricks.

```
import os
import requests

url = "https://endpoint_service"

headers = {
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'MyKey',
  'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'
}

def send_audio_transcript(url, payload, header):
    """Send audio.mp3 to a Azure service to be transcripted to text."""
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

full_path = <my_path>file.mp3
with open(full_path, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()

send_audio_transcript(url, fileContent, headers) # a POST request its works
```

But my audio files are in a **sensitive storage** in Data lake and the only  way to access them is by spark read.
looking for the documentation the way to read a binary file is.

```
df = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(full_path)

display(df)
```

path ||   modificationTime  || length     ||   content

---

path  ||    sometime        ||    some_lenght  ||   2dnUwAC

first try:

```
 content = df.content
 test_service = send_audio_transcript(url, content , headers)
```

`ValueError:` Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Second try(convert spark to pandas):

```
 pandas_df = df.toPandas()
 content = pandas_df["content"]
 test_service = send_audio_transcript(url, content , headers)
```

`Valuerror:`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What is the exactly translate in python-pyspark to:

```
with open(full_path, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
```

Comment: You need to post a link to the library and method that you are using.  Typically, binary is zero and ones.  To send this data over the internet using a POST method, the data need to be encoded into text using some type of algorithm such as base-64.  For some reason, it works locally using python but not remotely using PySpark.  The question is why.  Need more details ...

Comment: Hi it just not work locally its work in the same enviroment ( Databricks - python) the problem comes instead read the file with "with open(path)... I read the file with spark.read. my question is just simply what is the equivalente to "with open" but in Spark read

Comment: Hi @CRAFTY I post the library and the compleaty method and librareis in case it could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content data comming from Spark is not the same as the content data comming from open file.
From spark and later pandas you have a `pandas series` but from open the file you will have a `class bytes`

```
with open(full_path, mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    fileContent = file.read()
print(type(fileContent)) # will return  <class 'bytes'>
```

but from Spark

```
 input_df = spark.read.format("binaryFile").load(full_path)   
 pandas_df = input_df.toPandas()
 content = pandas_df['content']
 print(type(content)) # return <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

In your case to fix your problem you need to take just the first element of the series.

```
 content_good = content[0] 
 print(content_good) # you have your <class 'bytes'> wich is what you need
```